# how to filter all products by custom dropdown attribute value in magento?

Tags: zend-framework, magento, magento-1.4, magento-1.5

i have created a custom dropdown attribute with a name "**by_item**", and added some options to it like "Suite, Bridal, Jeans" etc.

```
<?php   // get all products
        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');

        //filter codition
        $collection->addFieldToFilter(array(
                        array('attribute'=>'by_item','eq'=>"Suite"),
                    ));

        foreach ($collection as $product) {

        var_dump($product->getData());
    }

    ?>
```

It gives nothing :(

but when i do this :

```
<?php 
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');

    //filter codition
    //$collection->addFieldToFilter(array(
    //                array('attribute'=>'by_item','eq'=>"Suite"),
    //            ));

    foreach ($collection as $product) {
    echo $product->getName() . "<br />";


}

?>
```

it gives me all names of products . I have visited many articles but didn't come across any question :(

Comment: is there anything i might be missing ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This doesn't work because you use the OR version (nested arrays) of `addFieldToFilter()`.

What you want is the AND version. Try this:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addFieldToFilter('by_item', array('eq' => 'Suite'));

foreach ($collection as $product) {
    var_dump($product->debug());
}
```

EDIT

Overlooked that the OP was talking about a "Dropdown" attribute (not a textfield).

When using `addFieldToFilter()` to filter by a "Dropdown" attribute, you must use the option's **value/id**, but not the option's text/label.

For example, if your custom dropdown attribute has this options

```
id    text
12    Suite
13    Bridal
14    Jeans
```

and you want to filter by "Suite", you code it like this:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addFieldToFilter('by_item', array('eq' => '12'));
```

You could also use your option's text/label indirectly:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addFieldToFilter(
        'by_item',
        array(
            'eq' => Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')
                        ->getAttribute('by_item')
                        ->getSource()
                        ->getOptionId('Suite')
        )
    );
```

Comment: tnx @Jurgen thelen , but still no luck :(

Comment: Strange. If I use this on an attribute I added to catalog, it works properly. How did you add your `by_item` attribute?

Comment: These are my options respectively:
by_item, Global, Dropdown, No, No, None, All Producs Type, No, Yes, Yes, Yes, Filterable (with results), Yes, No, 0, Yes Yes, Yes.

Comment: i have written just the values, hope you will understand

Comment: Also this works for me:
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('name', 'product1');

Comment: Oh wait, you use a Dropdown? Sorry, overlooked that. You need to filter for the **value** of the option, not its **name**, then. For example if your options are 12 = "Suite", 13 ="Bridal", etc. you need to filter for "12" if you want to filter "Suite".

Comment: Need to remove `;` after `getCollection()` - all good otherwise :)